# How to add progressbar when excuting the bat file using c#?

Tags: c#, batch-file, progress-bar

How to add progressbar when excuting the bat file?

I have c# code below:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Downloads\\install_ubuntu2";
        string batFileName = path + ".bat";

        using (StreamWriter batFile = new StreamWriter(batFileName))
        {
            batFile.WriteLine("wsl.exe -u root apt update");
            batFile.WriteLine("wsl.exe -u root apt --assume-yes install xwayland");
            batFile.WriteLine("wsl.exe -u root apt --assume-yes install libegl-dev");
            batFile.WriteLine("wsl.exe -u root DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt --assume-yes install lightdm");
            batFile.WriteLine("wsl.exe -u root apt --assume-yes install ubuntu-desktop");
            batFile.WriteLine("wsl.exe -u root wget -O /tmp/install-sg.sh --content-disposition \"https://gist.githubusercontent.com/djfdyuruiry/6720faa3f9fc59bfdf6284ee1f41f950/raw/952347f805045ba0e6ef7868b18f4a9a8dd2e47a/install-sg.sh\"");
            batFile.WriteLine("wsl.exe -u root chmod +x /tmp/install-sg.sh");
            batFile.WriteLine("wsl.exe -u root /tmp/install-sg.sh && rm /tmp/install-sg.sh");
            batFile.WriteLine("wsl.exe -u root sed -i 's/240/3/g' /etc/genie.ini");
            batFile.WriteLine("wsl.exe --shutdown");
            batFile.WriteLine("wsl whoami > test1.txt");
            batFile.WriteLine("set /P Var=<test1.txt ");
            batFile.WriteLine("Set Var1=/home/%Var%/.bashrc");
            batFile.WriteLine("wsl.exe -u root echo \"genie -i\" ^>^> \"%Var1%\"");
            batFile.WriteLine("wsl.exe -u root echo \"genie -c Xwayland & \" ^>^> \"%Var1%\"");
            batFile.WriteLine("wsl.exe -u root echo \"timeout 20\" ^>^> \"%Var1%\"");
            batFile.WriteLine("wsl.exe -u root echo \"genie -c gnome-session & \" ^>^> \"%Var1%\"");

            batFile.WriteLine("powershell -Command \"Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force -Scope CurrentUser\"");
            batFile.WriteLine("powershell -Command \"Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser\"");
            batFile.WriteLine("powershell -Command \"Install-Module VirtualDesktop -Force -Scope CurrentUser\"");
            batFile.WriteLine("powershell -Command \"Import-Module VirtualDesktop\"");
            batFile.WriteLine("powershell -Command \"New-Desktop\"");
            //batFile.WriteLine("PAUSE");
        }

        ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + batFileName);
        processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;

        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();

        File.Delete(batFileName);
    }
```

I have to know to cmd execution progress and add a progressbar.

The progressbar's code is [enter link description here](https://www.itread01.com/content/1547190426.html).

How to achieve that?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why do you use a batch file for executing the commands. Would it not be better to use Process to execute the commands step by step, then you could use [IProgress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1?view=net-6.0) to update the progressbar.

Comment: Hi Caveman, I don't understand well. Could you give me the sample code? I am new for c#. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows Forms you could do something like this (In this version without the use of `IProgress`):

```cs
    void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var listOfCommands = InitializeListOfCommands();
        var numberOfItems = listOfCommands.Count();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++)
        {
            RunCommand(listOfCommands[i].Cmd, listOfCommands[i].Parameter);
            ProgressProgressBar.Value = (i + 1) * 100 / numberOfItems;
        }
    }

    List<(string Cmd, string Parameter)> InitializeListOfCommands()
    {
        return new List<(string Cmd, string Parameter)>()
        {
            ("wsl.exe", "-u root apt update"),
            ("wsl.exe", "-u root apt --assume-yes install xwayland"),
            // next commands
        };
    }

    void RunCommand(string cmd, string arguments)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(cmd, arguments);
        processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;

        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
    }
```

Keep in mind:

- the example above is running synchronously
- keep an eye on the error handling when Process returns an errorlevel